# How Can i conditions of the query as a column in the data

Tags: sql

i want get a SQL like the pic~
now i want get the result by Top 3 projectId (4,3,2) total 8 result.
so how can i mody my sql?
( the SQL in real project is so complex~,about 10 my DBTable and 10 SAP table~ i concerned about efficiency so i don't want use temporary table)
can u help me~?[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `SQL Server`, use `TOP`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ProjectID IN
(
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 ProjectID
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY ProjectID DESC
)
ORDER BY ProjectID Desc
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c646b/5)

Comment: an sorry that i did't articulate~~ the result of the photo that i using SQL to query, and now i want to query the result again  ,condition to ‘ProjectAid’ 。sorry for my pool english~~ thank u~~ and cool dog!

Comment: hmm~dude~i edit my question~ my be u can understad me~~ no matter how~~thank u LOL~~

Comment: i know this and i know this solution~~but in real project,my sql is inner about 20 tables..~ i need write `Select top 5 xxxx from ( select xxx from table1 inner Join xxx on xxx=xxx~~ long long sql here~~)tmp1 ` order by project Aid ... is a hard work..

Comment: how will i answer your question if i don't know what are your tables is, what are the contents of your tables? I don't know if it contains duplicates. there are many possibilities. the best way to do is to add sample record on your question, and your desired result.]

Comment: ho guys . i got the sulution~ i get a DataSet~ an i write a func to get the data i want~~ thank u gus... cool dog agagin~~ lol

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL then:

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
   ORDER BY PROJECTAID ASC
   LIMIT 10;
```